# Video uploaded by certain android does not play on Google Chrome browser with HTML5

Tags: android, html, video, mp4, codec

In my web application, iPhone and android phone can upload video, it can play on both phones and desktop browser.

However certain android phones upload a video but it cannot play anywhere although it seems to be uploaded correctly.

I looked into to it and found a difference. Certain phone uploads a video file with Codecs "MPEG-4, AAC" and the others upload "H.264, AAC".

I'm currently using ReactJs and html5 video tag to play video. It looks there is no way to solve with video tag options.

[Device and photo information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZRpz.jpg)

[image]

Here is device and photo information. On your left side, ASUS phone uploaded video which has MPEG-4 video codecs, and it won't play.
On your right side, Galaxy phone video which has H.264 codecs, and it plays.
Both videos have same format mp4.

--

Additional information might help you is that even though you download that video and upload from desktop browser, it won't play as well. I would appreciate if you know solutions for it, thanks.

Comment: MPEG-4 isn't a codec, it's a container. The actual codec within the container may be the problem (can you share sample videos or check output of, say, `ffprobe`). You may need to transcode non-compliant videos to H264/aac on the server (eg using `ffmepg`)

Comment: MPEG 4 is not a container. It is a category. There are MPEG 4 containers, but there are also mpeg 4 codecs. AVC is an mpeg 4 codec. But so is aac and a variation of h.263. You should look at the Wikipedia page. There is a codec that is often refused to simply as mpeg4 and it is not supported by browsers.

Comment: Thank you guys, I appreciate for your answers. In either case MPEG-4 is container or category, it should be convert to compatible format not to be refused by browser, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer for this question is converting video format using lambda and elastic transcoder.
see here: https://read.acloud.guru/easy-video-transcoding-in-aws-7a0abaaab7b8

According to my research About MPEG-4, it is neither codec nor container. MP4 is a standard format container for audio and video used by MPEG-4. The point is MPEG-4 is a standard specification.

Thanks @Offbeatmammal and @szatmary to comment on this issue.